# Nodejs mongostore creating thousands of sessions without activity when deployed to GAE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine

I have deployed my project written in node.js deployed to GAE. It manages sessions by using mongostore:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'hakunamatata',
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    autoRemove: 'interval',
    autoRemoveInterval: 10
  })
}))
```

However when deployed, my mongodb cloud database gets hit all the time increasing the number of sessions in store by multiple per second ish.

What is doing this and how do I disable it? I dont want to fill my 512MB of free mongodb storage for development..

[image: deployed for 30 minutes]

Update:
Now its over a million documents in sessions
[image: over million]

Comment: Does this not happen when you run the project locally?

Comment: Not that I can see no. They point to the same mongodb instance on mongo cloud.

Comment: Have you tried all basic troubleshooting procedures? Check how many users are logging in every second. Maybe a bot is hitting your site

Comment: No user is logged in, this is early development so no one knows the adress.

Comment: Also, there is no activity on the GAE console page either

Comment: Can you confirm on your local files if a session is created only on login or even when sending get requests?

Comment: Confirmed. It doesnt create a new document in sessions collection, but the sessions grows.

Comment: Could you try to disable the saving of uninitialized sessions? Add this two options above auto remove: saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false. Sadly I never has this problem and I am just trying to think of possible causes

Comment: Added and deploying now. Will write when I see anything

Comment: No difference. Still bashing my db with sessions. 2500 since deployment a couple of minutes ago.
Switched db to see difference. The old one stopped increasing and the new one is blooming.

Comment: You will have to wait for other people to give their opinion. :( This is the first time I see this problem.

Comment: Okey, will do. Thanks for trying though, appreciate it!